# Intervals and sets

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, notation

I never took calculus until now, but as a stat major I have sometimes used the notation $x\in [a, b]$ as an alternative way of writing $a\leq x \leq b$. Does it make sense to express it like this, or is this incorrect? Or should I be using something like $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : a\leq x \leq b\}$?

Comment: $[a,b]=\{x\in\mathbb R:a\leq x \leq b\}$. The complement of $[a,b]$ is $(-\infty,a)\cup(b,\infty)$.

Comment: It's correct and is used a lot. Also, you can use $x\in (a,b)$ to express $a\lt x\lt b$.

Comment: @IanColey Cool. Good to know I haven't been making a fool of myself for a while!

Comment: I'm assuming that by the statement, "using $x\in [a, b]$ as a complement to $a\leq x \leq b$", you mean to assert that $x\in [a, b]$ is equivalent to $a\leq x \leq b$.

Comment: @Alraxite Oh, yes. Sorry for the unfortunate word choice; I don't mean the mathematical complement - just a variation of how to express the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

One may want to distinguish two kinds of things:

1. $x\in [a,b]$ and $a\le x\le b$ are *statements* about $x$. (They are the same statement written in different ways.)
2. $[a,b]$ and $\{x\in\mathbb R: a\le x\le b\}$ are *sets*. (They are the same set written in different ways.)

It is very common to mix the notation, e.g., to talk about "the measure of the set $x\ge 2$". The meaning is usually clear from context. But personally,  I prefer not to use 1 when I mean 2.